# Visual Studio Code Extension : List tasks with typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to develop an extension for VS Code, but I have an issue regarding the commands.

I'm starting to list the tasks of the current project but I have no idea on how achieve that.

I have started this piece of code but I don't know if it is relevant or not :

```
let test = vscode.commands.executeCommand('task');
```

Thanks in advance for the help.
Kind regards.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do with your extension?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about what you want to do, I can only guess.

You wrote:

> I'm starting to list the tasks of the current project

I assume you mean that you want to list the tasks that are written in "tasks.json".

Unfortunately, the API does not expose this.

As a workaround you can try to read the file yourself by looking at the workspace root for `.vscode/tasks.json`, reading the file, and trying to parse it yourself.

Something like:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const tasksFile = path.join(vscode.workspace.rootPath, 'tasks.json');
    const buffer = fs.readFileSync(tasksFile);
    const tasks = buffer.toJSON().data;
    console.dir('tasks', tasks);
}
```